# Isomorphism between different definitions of Integers

Tags: equivalence-relations, integers

Sorry for the wall-of-text in advance, hope some of you make it till the end ;)

When constructing the integers from the natural numbers, I've been using the following definitions. Let $\sim$ be an equicalence relation, which for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
(a,b)\sim (c,d):\Leftrightarrow a+d=b+c.
\end{align*}
The set of integers is then defined as the set
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}_{1}:=\{[(a,b)]_{\sim}\mid (a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\}.
\end{align*}
Note that every equivalence class $[(a,b)]_{\sim}$ can be written either as $[(n,0)]_{\sim}$ or as $[(0,n)]_{\sim}$, so we define for all $\hat{n}\in\mathbb{Z}_{1}$
\begin{align*}
\hat{n}&:=[(n,0)]_{\sim}
\\
-\hat{n}&:=[(0,n)]_{\sim}.
\end{align*}

Now, addition $\oplus$, multiplication $\odot$, and total order $\preceq$ on $\mathbb{Z}_{1}$ are defined as
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)]_{\sim}\oplus[(c,d)]_{\sim}&:=[(a+c,b+d)]_{\sim}
\\
[(a,b)]_{\sim}\odot[(c,d)]_{\sim}&:=[(ac+bd,ad+bc)]_{\sim}
\\
[(a,b)]_{\sim}\preceq [(c,d)]_{\sim}&:\Leftrightarrow a+d\leq b+c.
\end{align*}

When starting with the real numbers, we can define the natural numbers as intersection of all inductive sets. With the definition
\begin{align*}
-\mathbb{N}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \exists n\in\mathbb{N}:x=-n\}
\end{align*}
we then can define the integers as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}_{2}:=-\mathbb{N}\cup \mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}

Since we started with the real numbers, addition $+$, multiplication $\cdot$ and total order $\leq$ on the set $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ are given by the axioms of the real numbers.

I would like to prove that the sets $\mathbb{Z}_{1}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ are (at least up to isomorphism) identical. My idea was to use a map $f:(-\mathbb{N}\cup\mathbb{N})\rightarrow (\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$, defined as
\begin{align*}
f(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
[(n,0)]_{\sim}&\text{for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}
\\
[(0,n)]_{\sim}&\text{for $n\in -\mathbb{N}$}.
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
So I have to show the following:

1. $f$ is bijective.
2. For all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ we have $f(x+y)=f(x)\oplus f(y)$.
3. For all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ we have $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\odot f(y)$.
4. For all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ we have $x\leq y\Leftrightarrow f(x)\preceq f(y)$.

I've proven the first property but I'm struggling with the second one. My approach to prove the second property was to distinguish between the following four cases:

1. Let $(x\in\mathbb{N})$ and $(y\in\mathbb{N})$. This case works out just fine; We have $f(x)=[(x,0)]_{\sim}$ and $f(y)=[(0,y)]_{\sim}$. Because $x+y\in\mathbb{N}$ we also have $f(x+y)=[(x+y,0)]_{\sim}$. Using the definition of $\oplus$ we also get $f(x)\oplus f(y)=[(x+y,0)]_{\sim}$. Therefore we have
   \begin{align*}
   f(x+y)=f(x)\oplus f(y).
   \end{align*}
2. Let $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y\in -\mathbb{N}$. Then we have $f(x)=[(x,0)]_{\sim}$ and $f(y)=[(0,y)]_{\sim}$ and, as a consequence
   \begin{align*}
   f(x)\oplus f(y)=[(x,y)]_{\sim}.
   \end{align*}
   Next it could be that $x+y\leq 0$ or $0\leq x+y$, so we have to consider two or three subcases. And this is where my trouble starts, because now we have the cases 1) $x+y \leq 0$. Then $f(x+y)=[(0,x+y)]_{\sim}$, and 2) $0\leq x+y$. Then $f(x+y)=[(x+y,0)]_{\sim}$. Note, that in the case $x+y=0$, we have $f(x+y)=[(x+y,x+y)]_{\sim}$.
   Somehow I have to find a way to show that for $0\leq x+y$ we have
   \begin{align*}
   [(x+y,0)]_{\sim}=[(x,y)]_{\sim}
   \end{align*}
   and for $x+y\leq 0$ we have
   \begin{align*}
   [(0,x+y)]_{\sim}=[(x,y)]_{\sim}
   \end{align*}
   Does anyone have an idea or is my approach totally wrong? Proving the next two cases shouldn't be a big issue after this.
3. Let $x\in-\mathbb{N}$ and $y\in\mathbb{N}$.
4. Let $x,y\in-\mathbb{N}$.

The proof of $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\odot f(y)$ and $x\leq y\Leftrightarrow f(x)\preceq f(y)$ will probably face the same issue.

It would be great if anyone could help me with this proof. Or is there a better way to proof the sets $\mathbb{Z}_{1}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ are the same?

Comment: If $x+y\le 0$ then according to your definition, $f(x+y)=[(0,x+y)]_\sim$, not $f(x+y)=[(x+y,0)]_\sim$

Comment: thanks for the hint, fixed it.

Comment: I think your $f$ needs to be adjusted too. Have you thought about $f(n)=[(0,-n)]_\sim$ if $n\in -\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: I think since $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ there shouldn't be any negatives in there. If $\hat{x}\in-\mathbb{N}$ we have $\hat{x}=[(0,x)]_{\sim}$ where $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If $n\in-\mathbb N$, then $(0,n)\not\in \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ for $n\neq 0$ (I think you use $0\in\mathbb N$), so that's why you have to change your definition. We have $-n\in\mathbb N$ for $n\in-\mathbb N$ (!)

Comment: Right, so let 
 \begin{align*}
 f(n)=
 \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
 [(n,0)]_{\sim} &\text{for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}
 \\ 
 \left[(-n,0)\right]_{\sim}&\text{for $n\in-\mathbb{N}$.}
 \end{array}\right.
 \end{align*}
 Let $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y\in-\mathbb{N}$. Then $f(y)=[(-y,0)]_{\sim}$. Furthermore, we have $f(x)=[(x,0)]_{\sim}$ and therefore $f(x)\oplus f(y)=[(x-y,0)]_{\sim}$. Because $y\in-\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(x+y)=f(x-y)=[(x-y,0)]_{\sim}$ (although I'm not quite sure how to formally justify that $y\in -\mathbb{N}$ implies $x+y=x-y$) and therefore $f(x+y)=f(x)\oplus f(y)$.

Comment: No, it is obviously not always true that $x+y=x-y$ (I mean try it: $1+1\neq 1-1$). The correct definition is \begin{align*}  f(n)=  \left\{\begin{array}{ll}   [(n,0)]_{\sim} &\text{for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}  \\   \left[(0,-n)\right]_{\sim}&\text{for $n\in-\mathbb{N}$.}  \end{array}\right.  \end{align*} If $x\ge 0\ge y$ with $x\ge -y$, for example, then (I will omit the $\sim$ in notation) $$f(x)=[(x,0)], \quad f(y)=[(0,-y)]$$ so $$f(x)\oplus f(y) = [(x,-y)]$$ and $$f(x+y)=[(x+y,0)].$$ So you want to prove $$[(x,-y)]=[(x+y,0)],$$ which is true, since $x+0=x+y-y$. I'll leave the other cases to you.

Comment: So I got the definition of $f$ wrong again. Yours on the other hand works out just fine, although I think for $f(x+y)$ we have to distinguish two cases. If $x+y\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(x+y)=[(x+y,0)]$ if $x+y\in -\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(x+y)=[(0, -(x+y)]$ but it can easily be shown that $[(x+y,0)]=[(0,-(x+y)]$. Also $[(x,-y)]=[(x+y,0)]$ is easy to prove, therefore $f(x+y)=f(x)\oplus f(y)$. I think now everything works out. Thanks so much for your help with this.

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: (In fact this is why I said $x\ge -y$ .)